# Baixa Performance ao consultar DataTable C# - Plan Coded Ui Test

Tags: c#

Estou com um problema de desemepnho ao consultar os números de um `DataTable-X` com um `DataTable-Y`, tenho que verificar se o número do `DataTable-X` existe no `DataTable-Y` (e caso encontre complementar o `DataTable-X` com os dados do `DataTable-Y`), da forma que estou fazendo gasto certa de **50 minutos**.

*Quantidade de Linhas de cada DataTable*:

> `DataTable-X => 38.258 linhas (10 colunas)`
>
> `DataTable-X => 61.235 linhas (4 colunas)`

Na prática, o `loop` ocorre `DataTable-X` x `DataTable-X` vezes, isso é muito, mas 50 minutos acho tempo de mais.

*Segue o código:*

```
for (int i = 0; i < dTx.Rows.Count; i++)
{    
    bool ganbis1 = false;
    foreach (DataRow oLinha in dTy.Rows)
    {
        if (oLinha[0] != "")
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt64(oLinha[0].ToString()) ==             
                 Convert.ToInt64(dTx.Rows[i][1].ToString().Replace(" ","")))
            {
                // dTx = "Coluna1", "Coluna2", "Coluna3", "Coluna4",
                // "Coluna5", "Coluna6", "Coluna7", "Coluna8", "Coluna9", "Coluna10"
                
                // dTy = "Coluna1", "Coluna2", "Coluna3","Coluna4"
                // Preenche coluna 7
                
                if ((Convert.ToString(oLinha[1]) == "") || 
                    (Convert.ToString(oLinha[1]) == "#N/A"))
                {
                    dTx.Rows[i][7] = "#n/D";
                }
                else
                {
                    dTx.Rows[i][7] = Convert.ToString(oLinha[1]);    
                }
                // Preenche coluna 8
                if ((Convert.ToString(oLinha[2]) == "") || (Convert.ToString(oLinha[2]) == "#N/A"))
                {
                    dTx.Rows[i][8] = "#n/D";
                }
                else
                {
                    dTx.Rows[i][8] = Convert.ToString(oLinha[2]);
                }
                // Preenche coluna 9
                if ((Convert.ToString(oLinha[3]) == "") || (Convert.ToString(oLinha[3]) == "#N/A"))
                {
                    dTx.Rows[i][9] = "#n/D";
                }
                else
                {
                    dTx.Rows[i][9] = Convert.ToString(oLinha[3]);
                }
                // Preenche coluna 10
                if ((Convert.ToString(oLinha[4]) == "") || (Convert.ToString(oLinha[4]) == "#N/A"))
                {
                    dTx.Rows[i][10] = "#n/D";
                }
                else
                {
                    dTx.Rows[i][10] = Convert.ToString(oLinha[4]);
                }            
                ganbis1 = true;
            }
        } 
    }   
}

if ((ganbis1 == false) && (i != dTx.Rows.Count-1))
{
    // Quando não for encontrado preencher com #n/D
    dTx.Rows[i][7] = "#n/D";
    dTx.Rows[i][8] = "#n/D";
    dTx.Rows[i][9] = "#n/D";
    dTx.Rows[i][10] = "#n/D";    
}
```

Comment: Você traz os dados do banco de dados? Se for banco de dados não poderia fazer uma comparação SQL  e fazer essa operação no banco de dados?

Comment: Infelizmente eu tenho que fazer a leitura de N arquivos xlsx, e ao realizar esse tratamento gravo em um novo xlsx com tudo unificado.

Comment: Entendi @D1Dih mas, se você fizesse assim, a leitura de dados jogar em duas tabelas no banco de dados (poderia ser até temporárias) e depois fazer um procedure para agilizar o processo e logo após o resultado gerar novamente os xlsx?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic entendi. Essa forma é possível fazer sim. Você acredita não haver melhoria na forma utilizada acima?

Comment: Não sei dizer pra você e mensurar, mas, é lento realmente ler tantas linhas e ficar comparando dois itens muito grandes na memória, na minha opinião você precisa organizar os dados primeiramente (eu jogaria isso num banco de dados) e depois extrair os dados. Esse processo pode melhorar o desempenho visto que dados organizados e lógicos tende ser mais fácil comparar ... !!!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Bem observador e boa sugestão.

Comment: Segui essa linha de organizar os dados e incluir um break quando encontrar o item. Ordenei as colunas que estou comparando em ordem crescente:

DataView dv = dTx.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "Nome da coluna a ser ordenada Asc";
dTx = dv.ToTable();
   
DataView dvTwo = dTy.DefaultView;
dvTwo.Sort = "Nome da coluna a ser ordenada Asc";
dTy = dvTwo.ToTable();

Em sequência inclui um break quando encontrar o elemento da busca, para que o laço não continue processando após encontrar.

Comment: haaa... isso reduziu pela metade o tempo de processamento. :)

Answer (score 2):

Você está iterando sobre esses arrays 2342728630 vezes, convertendo strings e comparando em todas as iterações. Não me surpreende que que esteja demorando.

Acredito que o mínimo que você possa fazer seja criar um array associativo para evitar um for dentro de outro for, dessa forma você só precisaria percorrer cada array uma vez, reduzindo as iterações para 99493.

```
Dictionary<long, DataRow> dic = new Dictionary<long, DataRow>();

foreach (DataRow oLinhaX in dTx.Rows) { 
    dic.Add(Convert.ToInt64(oLinhaX[1].ToString().Replace(" ",""))), oLinhaX);
}

foreach (DataRow oLinhaY in dTy.Rows) {
    if (oLinhaY[0] == "") continue;

    long oLinhaYInt = Convert.ToInt64(oLinhaY[0].ToString());

    if (dic.ContainsKey(oLinhaYInt)) {
        DataRow oLinhaX = dic[oLinhaYInt];
        //seu código aqui
    }
}
```

Isso deve dar uma boa aliviada, mas ainda espere alguns minutos de processamento. Quer mais desempenho? Parta para uso de múltiplos núcleos.

**Edit**

Não foi mencionado na pergunta, mas essa solução só funciona se a relação entre as tabelas for one-to-one.

Comment: Muito boa a sua resposta, vi que você é novo no site, depois de uma olhada no nosso código de conduta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct e se inteire de como nossa comunidade trabalha.

Answer (score 1):

Tem aqui uma outra forma de abordar o problema:

```
var rowsX = dtX.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => r[1].ToString().Trim());
var rowsY = dtY.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => r[0].ToString() != string.Empty).Select(r => r[0].ToString());

var rows = rowsX.Intersect(rowsY);
var dataRowsX = dtX.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => rows.Contains(r[1]));

foreach (var row in dataRowsX)
{
    var dataRowY = dtY.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().FirstOrDefault(r => r[0].ToString() == row[1].ToString());

    // código...
}
```

Basicamente compara as linhas dos dois `DataTable` e depois intersecta num só.

Por fim, utiliza essa intersecção para percorrer o `DataTable-X` e obtendo, para cada linha, o `DataTable-Y` para alteração de valores.

Comment: consegue me explicar melhor. Infelizmente pra mim o cast não foi reconhecido no dtX/dtY. Para reconhecer tiver que usar dataset.table[nome da tabela].Rows.Cast... Gostaria de testar sua sugestão para aferir o tempo de processamento.

Comment: Qual dos casts não foi reconhecido? O `dtX.Rows.Cast<DataRow>`?

Comment: Na verdade todos os cast não reconheceram. E sobre meu comentário sobre dataset acima, num tem nada haver, também não reconheceu.

Comment: Ha, provavelmente precisa do `using System.Linq` para funcionar :)

Comment: isso mesmo :D. Conseguir compilar até o foreach, Agora apresenta a msg 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.'. Eu estou debugando para entender sua sugestão, porque ainda não entendi :)

Comment: Parti do princípio que a informação que constava das linhas era texto, mas sendo numérico dá erro mesmo. Alterei tudo para `ToString()`. Experimente de novo.

Comment: Sei que uma pergunta escrota, mas eu não tenho usado expressões lambda e o debug vou bem transparente :D... seria possível explicar o que fez esses trechos?
'var rowsX = dtX.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => r[1].ToString().Trim());'

Comment: Basicamente cria um enumerado com todos os valores, convertidos para `String`, da coluna 1 de cada linha da tabela X (nesse caso).